# SWIFT - Why get always error when I want post?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a project which is like a twitter app. Everything works except this one. When I try to Share Something I always get a SIGBART ERROR.

```
@IBAction func post(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in



        let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let username = data["username"]
        let userImg = data["userImg"]

        let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            "username": username as AnyObject,
            "userImg": userImg as AnyObject,
            "postText": self.postText.text as AnyObject
        ]

        let firebasePost = Database.database().reference().child("textPosts").childByAutoId()
        firebasePost.setValue(post)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This is my code. The SIGBART is on the "let data = snapshot ..."

Although I got this problem in the console:
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x104721850) to 'NSDictionary' (0x104721288).
(lldb)

Comment: print `snapshot.value` and check if it has value

Comment: Yes it is "nil", how can I solve that?

Comment: use it like -> snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Comment: use `guard let` or `if let` to wrap it. Something like `guard let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else {return}` @TreszlerDonát

Comment: @vivekDas Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1):

You are getting null value and you are forcefully converting it to dictionary. so, you are getting crash. So, first check if snapshot has children or not as written below.

```
@IBAction func post(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
       if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
          let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
          let username = data["username"]
          let userImg = data["userImg"]

          let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            "username": username as AnyObject,
            "userImg": userImg as AnyObject,
            "postText": self.postText.text as AnyObject
          ]

          let firebasePost = Database.database().reference().child("textPosts").childByAutoId()
          firebasePost.setValue(post)
       }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened. I didn't get error but not working

Comment: Are you sure there is a value at your defined node?

Comment: Not my program, I need to fix it. I found a lot error but that is the last.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is not any value at your defined node.

Comment: @TreszlerDonát Make sure your `"users"` table have requested `userID` and that `userID` should have data in it.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You better not to use force unwrap in case `as!` if you not sure that property would have a value at that moment. That's why Swift provides us with `Optional`.
Try this:
`guard let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }`
And for code readability it is better way to move code from `@IBAction` to separate function like `func updateDatabase(_ value: String, completion: () -> Void)`.